# ERROR: In <declare-styleable> MenuView, unable to find attribute android:preserveIconSpacing

Tags: android, view, declare-styleable

I had created an app and when tried to run,get an error like this.

```
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> MenuView, unable to find attribute android:preserveIconSpacing
```

Problems
[image]

and at end of R.java
[image]

please help me to fix this issue

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had the same problem in Eclipse, and fixed it by changing the API level by...

- Right Clicking on the project
- Open PROPERTIES > ANDROID
- Changed the API level down to the one I had been using up to now.

I think I was having the problem because I had just switched from API 21 to 22. I had read earlier that API 22 was trouble-some, so people were not using it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: While this will remove the error, it doesn't really fix the underlying problem and allow the OP to use API 22. The correct fix is to update the version of the appcompat library so that it is compatible with API 22.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. Update your appcompat version to 22.

Comment: to @ZachSperske & Code-Apprentice:  It may not be the best practice / correct answer... However, it allowed me to move forward with work on my practice. As with all programming - sometimes we programmers may not know what is 'best practice' - or sometimes 'best practice' is complicated and seems unnecessary when there is a simpler way to do it which seems to work just as fine.

Comment: Your solution prevents people from developing an app which targets the newer SDK. That's clearly not a good solution as it would trap your app on API 21. Stack overflow is about providing the most correct answer, yours is not a correct answer, just a workaround.

Comment: to @ZachSperske & Code-Apprentice: What is your solution that works?  I did try updating appcompat lib. before posting my answer, and that did not work for me.

Comment: what about api 23

Answer (score 17):

this error because you are using an old Appcompat version .. update Appcompat

to the newer version which is compatible with API 22

then click on fix project properties ..

working Fine with me :)

Hope This Help!!

Answer (score 11):

I think switched the API Level is not a genuine solution. We can resolve this by follows these steps:

1. Go to "C:\Users\AjaySharma\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\20.0.0\content\support\v7\appcompat\res\values\attrs.xml"

   (Pleae make sure , change USer name and Target version in path)
2. Find "android:preserveIconSpacing" in file and remove or comment this entire line.
3. Now, You can Build Seccessfully. For more details. [Read this](http://brendanzagaeski.appspot.com/xamarin/0000.html)

Comment: In OS X, the path for the step 1 is: `~/.local/share/Xamarin/Android.Support.v7.AppCompat/20.0.0/content/support/v7/appcompat/res/values/attrs.xml`

Comment: You're changing a system library. This is very hackish. I'd suggest a different API level.

Comment: Yes, you are saying right. But, for some change API level not works , So they can solve by doing this.

Comment: This is not the correct solution. We as Android developers should not change the source for the appcompat support library...unless we actively contribute to it.

Comment: Code-Apprentice If this is not the correct solution, then please tell the right solution so others can use that one to solve this issue.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed the problem by going to the path

> E:\adt-bundle-windows\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values\attrs.xml
>   and Find "android:preserveIconSpacing"

Then change it, From

```
attr name="preserveIconSpacing" format="boolean"
```

To

```
attr name="android:preserveIconSpacing"
```

also, remove

```
format="boolean"
```

Comment: You should not change the source code of the appcomat library. Instead you should update to the version of the library which are made for your chosen compileSdkVersion as described by Ramy Sky and Alexander Garner.

Answer (score 4):

In my case for the same error, when all else failed, I **removed** this line from `Gradle` config file, `myproject/app/build.gradle`

`config:compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'`

and, voila! It worked.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem after upgrading my version of Eclipse (and Google Plugin):

> ERROR: In  MenuView, unable to find attribute android:preserveIconSpacing

I have solved it by deleting the **appcompat**_v7 project from my workspace (and my disk).

And then creating a new Android project **MyApp1** - which has recreated the **appcompat_v7** project (here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BHsb.png)):

[image: screenshot]

After that I have deleted the **MyApp1** project again.

Answer (score -1):

if all the above answers don't work for you are probably missing

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

in you app build.gradle