# Error:com.android.builder.symbols.ResourceValuesXmlParseException: Unknown android attribute 'MenuView'

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, error-handling

I am VERY new to all this and I am literally not experienced in code. (However I am good at tweaking what already exists).

I purchased an app that was built on Eclipse and I needed to import it to Android Studio. I don't know if I fully imported everything correctly but I am trying to run my app to see if everything has been imported correctly and after fixing many errors i'm stumped and confused on how to fix this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':android-support-v7-appcompat:processDebugResources'.
>   Unknown android attribute 'MenuView'

When I run with info I get this message:

> Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':android-support-v7-appcompat:processDebugResources'.
>     Unknown android attribute 'MenuView'
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1s

And stacktrace gives me this:

> Error:com.android.builder.symbols.ResourceValuesXmlParseException: Unknown android attribute 'MenuView'

Here is my Manifest:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.designetxcs.superramboost"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="2.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/application_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Easyrambooster"
        tools:replace="android:theme">
        <activity
            android:name="com.raihanbd.easyrambooster.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/application_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.raihanbd.easyrambooster.QuickBoosterService" >
        </service>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
    </application>
```

And here is my gradle:

```js
apply plugin: 'android'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':android-support-v7-appcompat')
    compile project(':google-play-services_lib')
    compile project(':ProgressWheel')
    compile project(':ProgressWheel')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19


    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

I appreciate all the help.

UPDATE: I found this:

```js
static final int[] MenuView = { 0x010100ae, 0x0101012c, 0x0101012d, 0x0101012e, 0x0101012f, 0x01010130, 0x01010131, 0x01010435 };
  public static final int MenuView_android_headerBackground = 4;
  public static final int MenuView_android_horizontalDivider = 2;
  public static final int MenuView_android_itemBackground = 5;
  public static final int MenuView_android_itemIconDisabledAlpha = 6;
  public static final int MenuView_android_itemTextAppearance = 1;
  public static final int MenuView_android_preserveIconSpacing = 7;
  public static final int MenuView_android_verticalDivider = 3;
  public static final int MenuView_android_windowAnimationStyle = 0;
```

Maybe there something here that's wrong?

Comment: Have you read this question also? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29248579/error-in-declare-styleable-menuview-unable-to-find-attribute-androidpreserv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29248579/error-in-declare-styleable-menuview-unable-to-find-attribute-androidpreserv) 
I think you've a problem with the `appcompat` library version

Comment: I saw that post. but the instructions were for eclipse and I couldn't duplicate it on android studio

Comment: anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: anybody knows? I can't move on to publishing my app due to this issue.

Comment: Hey @DaBash, I know that the link refers to Eclipse, but that is important to some extent. Which version of `appcompat` are you using?