# How to fix "Android Studio build failed: Unknown android attribute 'MenuView'" error during :appcompat:generateDebugRFile task

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appcompat

I'm able to run new Android Studio projects perfectly, but I am trying to build an older project and keep receiving the error "Unknown android attribute 'MenuView'" during the :appcompat:generateDebugRFile task. I have tried using different gradle versions, different build tools versions, and changing the api level. I even tried the solutions for this similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29248579/error-in-declare-styleable-menuview-unable-to-find-attribute-androidpreserv) with no luck. The error definitely hints at an issue with the appcompat library, but android-support-v7 should be fine and I've found most instructions for updating the appcompat library to be outdated.

I'm really frustrated with this error (especially since I've been able to build the project recently in the past). Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed!

Turned out the gradle version that I was using was too new for the older project. When I tried to change to an older version in Android Studio, it wouldn't let me.

Solution was to checkout a fresh copy from git that used the older version and to not set gradle wrapper